# jQuery lightBox plug in - Show NEXT button all the time

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have switched to the jQuery lightBox plug in.

How do I set it so that the next and previous buttons always show. My users are not quick enough to know you have to mouse the mouse over the image to see more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the .lightBox() call

```
.lightBox({fixedNavigation:true})
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();
```

to

```
$('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox().lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery.lightbox.min.css change

```
#lightbox-nav-btnNext{display:block;width:49%;height:100%
```

to

```
#lightbox-nav-btnNext{display:block;width:0%;height:0%
```

Comment: ...this will "remove" the prev and next buttons